# How to run only selected test cases of a class in Selenium Automation testing project?

Tags: xslt, configuration, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have prepared a testng.xml file where I put number of test classes to run, for example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">  
    <!-- REMOTE PROJECT -->    
    <suite name="Suite1" preserve-order="true">
        <test name="Test1">
            <parameter name="browsers" value="Chrome">
            </parameter>
            <classes>               
                <class name="com.project.live.Class1" />    
                <class name="com.project.live.Class2" />    
                <class name="com.project.live.Class3" />
...
...
...
                <class name="com.project.live.Class...Nth" />
            </classes>


        </test>
        <!-- Test -->
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

There are test cases in these classes with `@Test Annotation`, I want to run selected test cases only i.e. I will skip some tests of these classes.
1. One way to do this is put `@Ignore Annotation` and remove `@Test Annotation` from tests which I don't want to run (but that's lengthy work, very time consuming)

2. Another way is to use `groups`but again it is lengthy to select tests and put them in groups.

**Query:**Is there any optimal way to achieve this, may be some customized config file?

Answer (score 1):

One way can be to use [Iannotationtransformer](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers).

Put another file which contains the list of cases to exclude (or include whichever list is shorter).  Implement the transform method to check whether the current method falls in this exclude list, if yes, then set the enabled property to false for the annotation and it would be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try IMethodInterceptor for this purpose?
Configure your test class with a listener implementing IMethodInterceptor and decide the tests to be run dynamically

A sample listener below.

public class MyTestListener implements IMethodInterceptor {

```
@Override
public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {

    List<IMethodInstance> methodlist = new ArrayList<IMethodInstance>();

    // Read these flags from somewhere, system var / test context / file or
    // where ever
    Boolean shouldRunTest1 = Boolean.valueOf(context.getAttribute("SHOULD_RUN_TEST1")
            .toString());
    Boolean shouldRunTest2 = Boolean.valueOf(context.getAttribute("SHOULD_RUN_TEST2")
            .toString());

    for (IMethodInstance iMethodInstance : methods) {

        // decide based on method name / group / priority / description or
        // what ever
        String methodName = iMethodInstance.getMethod().getMethodName();

        if (iMethodInstance.getMethod().isTest()) {
            if (shouldRunTest1 && methodName.equals("testCase1")) {
                methodlist.add(iMethodInstance);

            } else if (shouldRunTest2 && methodName.equals("testCase2")) {
                methodlist.add(iMethodInstance);

            }
        }
    }

    // Here we return the test cases to be run
    return methodlist;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

see the below example ,when u wanted to run only "sanity3" ,you can comment the other methods(sanity0 ....sanity2) and run using xml file (right click and Run as ->testng)

Eg:

```
                            <run>

            <!--  <include name="Sanity0"/>
            <include name="Sanity1"/>
            <include name="Sanity2"/> -->
            <include name="Sanity3"/>
```